# Difficulty in understanding the graph

Tags: graph-theory

A graph G has n vertices. For every 4 vertices in G, there is a vertex serving as the neighbor of the remaining 3 vertices. At least how many vertices are there neighboring all other vertices in G (i.e., vertices with degree n − 1)? Please explain your answers

I am given this question, yet I do not quite understand the question. According to my interpretation, for every 4 vertices in G... remaining vertices refer to a tree with three children, and three children for these children as well. I thought of the possibility which all vertices are of degree 3, yet how is it possible to have vertices with degree n-1, may anyone help me with understanding the problem, thank you.

Comment: "Among every 4 vertices there is one with an edge to the other three" could be a clearer formulation. Or, if you like, the subgraph induced by any 4 vertices contains a $K_{1,3}$. That means the graph must have be quite dense.

Comment: Then how is it possible to have vertices with degree n-1

Comment: The complete graph for example has this property.

Comment: The question does *not* say that one of the four vertices has the other three as neighbours *and has no other neighbours*.

Comment: So what actually does the sentence mean, i still don't get it, may you give me some hints on how to start on this question?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best way to be clear about a problem’s interpretation is to try to solve it!

Suppose that vertices a & b are not adjacent. Then every other pair of vertices not including a or b must form an edge. So if a second edge is missing from the graph, it must be wlog ac. A third missing edge can only be bc. So at least n-3 vertices must have degree n-1.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand the logic u are making use of, how does it relate with the conditions given, thxxxx

Comment: Hi every subgraph on 4 vertices {a,b,c,d} must contain at least one vertex of degree three. So if ab is not an edge then cd must be one